# Add different intents of different sub-directories of the website

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Say I have my website at: https://www.domain.tld/

Is it possible to add different intents in the sense:

https://www.domain.tld/ will open some activity

https://www.domain.tld/directory 1 will open some other activity

https://www.domain.tld/direcotry2 will open some other activity... and so on?

I have a gradle-based Android Studio project written mainly in Java, if that helps.

Also, as of now, I have an intent as follows:

https://www.domain.tld/ opens some activity

https://subdomain.domain.tld/ opens some other activity.

To accomplish this, I have used Android Studio's URL Mapping Editor as follows:

I have added https://www.domain.tld as the Host, I have chosen the option path and left its text field blank and mapped it to the required activity.

I have thought about trying pathPrefix and pathPattern, but, I don't think it'll work in my case. If I had to map just the sub-directories, it was easy, but, I need to maintain a seperate intent for the root directory of my website. So, the path, pathPrefix as well as pathPattern, will contain my root-directory and so, it might not work (this is a guess). Also, I'm not very sure about what pathPattern means.

So, I'm thinking of moving the sub-domain to a sub-directory in my website. I'll do so, only if it's possible to handle the intents as I have mentioned above.

I think, it's possible, just don't know very well, how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding pathPattern you can check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element#path).

The below support for pathPattern would help you in to handle the host URL only.

> An asterisk ('*') matches a sequence of 0 to many occurrences of the
>   immediately preceding character.

As per your needs, Android Studio's URL Mapping Editor will help you to create the below intent filters for the URLs in order to open a specific Activity. 
More details is available [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing).

```
     <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="www.domain.tld"
                android:scheme="https" 
                android:pathPattern="/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.domain.tld"
                android:pathPrefix="/directory1" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Main3Activity"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.domain.tld"
                android:pathPrefix="/directory2" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```